# How to design UI for Phone and Tablet in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

We are developing a iOS shopping cart application in c# and visual studio 2017 for xamarin, We are using Web Service, I am using listview as table format, whenever i run application with different device like iphone and ipad then that the alignment is not good so that How to design UI for Phone and Tablet in Xamarin forms

Comment: Give me any suggestion to resolve this issue

Comment: https://blog.xamarin.com/adaptive-ui-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Thank you for reply, i am working on it

Answer (score 0):

Creating a UI in xamarin.forms can be roughly compared to creating a html page with css styling:

You tell the framework, which elements you want to have on your screen, but as every browser (or in this case every mobile phone/operating system) has its own implementation on how that element should finally look like and behave, you end up in making some styling adjustments or adapations to your initial element.

Furtunately Xamarin.Forms already takes a good amount of the styling work from you, but there will always be some differences depending on which target system your app will be running. 
In order to get that straight, you will have to use the  Tags in xamarin.forms xaml, as well as custom renderers in your native implementation or effects in order to tweak your initial design description to match what you want to have on the individual target device.